# How to pass an array to action parameter as a list using jQuery in ASP.NET Core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I'm trying to pass an array to action parameter that is a list of ints. I want to do that using jQuery and in url it must show

```
/compare?ids=1&ids=2&ids=5
```

It can have so many ids and there is no limitation in number of ids.
I tried so many solutions and searched a lot but they didn't help.
This is what I tried but in action parameter it returns count 0.

This is my jQuery:

```
var pIds = [];

$('input:hidden.ids').each(function () {
    pIds.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(pIds);
var json = JSON.stringify(pIds);
console.log(json);

$.map(data.Value, function (element) {
    resultList.append('<li><a href="/Compare?"' + json + '>' +
                      '<span class="search__result-item search__result-icon 
                       search__result-icon--search">' +
                      element.Title +
                      ' </span><span class="search__result-item--category">' +
                      element.Price +
                      "</span></a></li>");
});
```

This is the action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProductsCompare(List<int> ids)
{           
    ViewBag.ids = ids;
    var products = await productGlobalService.ShowProductsForCompare(ids);
    return View(products.Value);
}
```

When I log the array in console it returns the ids in array form but I don't know how to pass it in href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the array like this

```
$('input:hidden.ids').each(function() {
    pIds.push(`ids=${$(this).val()}`);
});
```

and then join them together like `pIds.join('&')`

Also, you can use template literals to make your code a little more readable

```
var pIds = [];
$('input:hidden.ids').each(function() {
  pIds.push(`ids=${$(this).val()}`);
});
console.log(pIds);
$.map(data.Value, function(element) {
  resultList.append(
    `<li><a href="/Compare?${pIds.join('&')}">
    <span class="search__result-item search__result-icon 
    search__result - icon--search ">${element.Title}
    </span><span class="search__result-item--category">${element.Price}
    </span></a></li>`
  );
});
```